# Circuit Using only NAND and NOT Gates

Tags: digital-logic

I have the following expressions for some logic which will each power a motor:

1. A OR (NOT B) OR D
2. NOT(A AND C) or (NOT C AND D)

I have a limitation on the number of integrated circuits I can use, with each IC being able to hold 6 of any 1 gate type on it.

I have tried below to turn both of the expressions below into circuits using only two types of gate, NOT and NAND gates, I know that I can create a NOT gate using a NAND gate with both of its inputs being into the NAND but I don't believe it makes too much of a difference for my requirements.

Circuit 1

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0YF2U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuit 2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ8tIk.png)</sup>

If possible, I want to be able to combine the circuits together, having 4 inputs A B C D with each of the outputs to the motor being separate I'm looking to keep the number of IC's as little as possible - 2 MAX.

Formatted the question since the first post made hardly any sense, Sorry!

Comment: please show some effort to solve the problem

Comment: web search `karnaugh map`

Comment: Sorry if i didnt make it clear, i already have solutions for both logic ciruits as follows 1. NOT(NOT A AND B AND NOT D) 2. NOT(A AND NOT D)AND NOT C. i just dont know how to turn these into only NAND/NOT circuits

Comment: There's no need for both NAND and NOT. You can create a NOT from a NAND (A NAND 1 => NOT A).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Harry. Please edit your question to add detail to it, don't put that into comments. Please can you put a schematic for your original expressions, the schematic editor here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: "ideally if it can use less than 6 NOT and 6 NAND gates that would be great" - why?

Comment: Bruce, I'm limited by the amount of IC's i can use (2), with each IC being able to hold 6 gates. so if it can be done with less than 12 of any type or 6 of two types of gates.

Comment: i changed the circuits to only use two types of gate, they should be equivalent in terms of their logic no?

Comment: Yeah sorry if i'm confusing you all, i'm not super good with any of this stuff!

Comment: no problem on the second one,  that's still really helpful though what you've said, thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: you could use a multiplexer

Answer (score 1):

You really cannot simplify \$A + \bar B + D\$.

But \$ \overline {A C} + \bar C D\$ can be simplified.  Take deMorgan's on first term.

\$ \bar A + \bar C + \bar C D = \bar A + \bar C ( 1 + D ) = \bar A + \bar C = \overline {A C}\$

No possibility of combining the two circuits.

So using NANDs as NOTs, you have 6 NANDs total.